# XPath Query does not seem to be working

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have been having some issues doing an xpath query in C#, with the caveat that I have never used namespaces before but I generally get the idea.  I first construct the xml document as such and create a namespace manager.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(metaDataStream);
nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
rootNode = doc.ChildNodes[1];
nsmgr.AddNamespace(string.Empty, rootNode.Attributes["xmlns"].Value);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", rootNode.Attributes["xmlns:xsi"].Value);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", rootNode.Attributes["xmlns:xsd"].Value);
```

Then later on in a different method in the class I attempt to query the xml as such....

```
XmlNodeList selectedNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//somenode", nsmgr);
```

and the selected node list always comes up with zero nodes selected from the xml text below.  Can someone direct me where I have gone wrong? (as a note the actual XML is not exactly this, but for privacy reason I am not allowed to expose it so I tried my best to obfuscate the data while retaining the same properties)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" uuid="urn:uuid:03565202-d53b-4f26-83a2-4d94964ed4be" xmlns="http://www.something.com/ext/2010/10/01">
  <somenode someattribute="somevalue">
  </somenode>
</ext>
```

Comment: Your XPath looks like it should work for the fake XML you provided, which begs the question "are you SURE that rootNode is actually what you think it is?"  If you haven't already, I'd try printing out the XML for it just before you make the SelectNodes call to ensure that it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is your use of `string.Empty` as the alias for the namespace. This works:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("def", rootNode.Attributes["xmlns"].Value);
...            
XmlNodeList selectedNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//def:somenode", nsmgr);
```

Basically so long as you *do* give it an alias, it works fine.

(Personally I prefer LINQ to XML over using XPath, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, but this will work if you prefer to use XPath.)

**EDIT**: The behavior is specified in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx as note to "prefix" argument:
"If the XmlNamespaceManager will be used *for resolving namespaces in an XML Path* Language (XPath) expression, *a prefix must be specified*. If an XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is the empty namespace."

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!  Looks like you know more than the people who wrote the microsoft online documentation who suggested string.Empty ;-)

Comment: Brian, don't forget to accept the answer. Please provide link to "online documentation ..." so someone can fix it (unless it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx which explicitly says "...for resolving namespaces in an XML Path Language (XPath) expression, a prefix must be specified..." in the note for the "prefix" argument).